# How to capture OAUTH2 clientapp from azure http function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have enabled Azure App services authentication and registered my function in AAD, and the client then uses OAUTH2 to get a token and then call the API using that token and this works fine.

But I am struggling to find the documentation about how I based on that token can get the Client Application name that the client used to authenticate in my code

Let’s say my function app is testauth and the client app for the mobile app is clienttest

They use the clientID and clientSecret from the clienttest to auth to the resourceId of testauth

So now in my C# code I want to know the name clienttest is that possible and if so how?

I read about claims but I cannot really put the puzzle together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the clientID of clienttest. If you manage a map of the client name to clientID in your function app, then you will be able to know the client name.

#### 1. You can get the token from http header. Here is the official documentation: [Retrieve tokens in app code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code)

AS you are using AAD as the provider, so you may get the access token from http header: **`X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN`**

#### 2. Then you can decode the token. It is a [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token), which contains 3 parts: header, payload and signature.

All of them are base64url encoded, and are concatenated using periods. So, you can either use popular JWT libraries to decode it or just base64url decode the payload part. Then you will get a JSON string. Finally, you can get the `appid` claim:

[image]

With the `appid` claim, you will know the client name.

---

**Update**

You can get app name you registered in Azure AD with [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

With `$filter` expression, you can get app details. Here is a sample request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//applications?$filter=appId eq '68a1189c-a6b0-48fe-908c-841916d72731'`

And you will get the following response:

[image]

You can see that the app's display name is included.

Comment: I understand but that means I have to deploy code every time I add a new app which is exactly what I m trying to avoid, but will use this as a backstop if there is no dynamic way of doing this

Comment: If only with token, I am afraid that there is no other better option. You may use database to keep the client name and ID, then you do not need to deploy again. Another choice is to make your client to call your function with additional query parameter which contains client name.

Comment: Oh, forget a solution. You can use [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get app details by app id. Here is a request sample: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//applications?$filter=appId eq '68a1189c-a6b0-48fe-908c-841916d72731'`

Comment: @MattDouhan Find another solution, check my update. Thanks